# Roman numerals kata in clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm learning clojure and I wrote this code to resolve the roman numerals kata:

```
(def romans (sorted-map-by >
             1000 "M"
             500 "D"
             400 "CD"
             100 "C"
             90 "XC"
             50 "L"
             40 "XL"
             10 "X"
             9 "IX"
             5 "V"
             4 "IV"
             1 "I"))

(defn roman-digit [arabic]
  (first (filter (fn [[key value]]
          (>= arabic key)) romans)))

(defn arabic-to-roman [arabic]
  (def roman (roman-digit arabic))
  (if (> arabic 0)
    (apply str (val roman) (arabic-to-roman (- arabic (key roman))))
    ""))
```

I want to know how could I get this code more efficient/idiomatic/clean. I'm sure I can to learn a lot of new stuff.

Thanks.

Comment: Use let instead of def in the the arabic-to-roman function

Comment: You should post this at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: This problem is available at 4clojure. Follow some of the top users and post your solution to see theirs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my stab at it.

```clj
(defn roman-digit [arabic]
  (first
    (filter #(>= arabic (first %))
      [[1000 "M" ]
       [500  "D" ]
       [400  "CD"]
       [100  "C" ]
       [90   "XC"]
       [50   "L" ]
       [40   "XL"]
       [10   "X" ]
       [9    "IX"]
       [5    "V" ]
       [4    "IV"]
       [1    "I" ]])))

(defn arabic-to-roman [arabic]
  (when (> arabic 0)
    (let [[arabic-diff roman] (roman-digit arabic)]
      (apply str roman (arabic-to-roman (- arabic arabic-diff))))))
```

What's going on here?

- When you have an ordered closed set of values that you eventually use as sequence anyway, using a vector of pairs in the right order needs much less ceremony.
- Never do `def` inside a condition like this. Think of `def` as declaration and definition of a global variable (symbol). For local scopes (bindings) use `let`.
- Prefer `when` over `if` especially if there is only one branch. Note that both `str` and `apply` do the right thing for `nil` (which is returned at the bottom of the recursion when `arabic` is 0).